# Javascript - Add event listener to multiple elements

Tags: javascript

I have multiple elements using the same event listener. Instead of repeating the same function three times, wow do I combine them to call the same event to each of the three elements? `cardNumber`, `cardExpiry`, and `cardCvc`

```
cardNumber.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});
cardExpiry.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});
cardCvc.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't use an Anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```js
cardCvc.addEventListener('change', foo);

function foo(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Separate the event handler function, and make an array of the element, then finally loop it to attach the event handler.

```
const eventHandler = function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
}

const items = [cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc];
items.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('change, eventHandler);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement Event delegation pattern

Basically it consists of assigning the event to the container of the elements, then verifying the name or type of the element you discard those that are not relevant to you and in logical consequence only those that are of interest to you would be affected. To know more visit this [publication](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) please

Here an example

```
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const displayError = document.getElementById("card-errors");

container.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  const target = event.target;

  if (target.nodeName !== "INPUT") return;

  displayError.textContent = event.error ? event.error.message : "";
});
```